# Freezer doesn't have a temperature control. Does the fridge thermostat control freezer temperature?

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Midea 3.1 Cu. Ft. Compact Refrigerator. 
There is a place to control temperature in the fridge part but not in the freezer part. 
Does making the temperature colder in the refrigerator make the temperature colder in the freezer or does the freezer stay at a constant temperature?

Comment: I was going to suggest that it would be sufficient to check if your ice remains frozen, but both Google and the FDA agree that this doesn't cut it; 32°F is too warm.  I initially thought the current [FDA recommendation](https://www.fda.gov/consumers/consumer-updates/are-you-storing-food-safely) 0°F may just have been a safety buffer, but apparently this was an intentional choice, replacing historical advice (possibly not from the FDA) of 14°F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brief google will yield [access to the user manual.](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/95/959ef135-d986-40e3-990b-d2e75cc167ee.pdf) I didn't do an extensive read, but it looks like one temperature control for both compartments.